# Convert Month name to month number SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

is there a function in ORACLE SQL to convert the month name to month number but just this without the day and the year?
for example i have FEB and i want to convert it in 02

Comment: In a sql query or you want to change your date format?

Comment: I am working in Oracle Data Integrator and i have a field with Monthname (FEB) and i want to convert it to Month number (02) so i need a function like monthnumber('myfield') which will convert the name of the month as a number

Comment: What is the data type of column?

Comment: the datatype is string

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT CASE month_name
       WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1
       WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2
       WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3
       WHEN 'APR' THEN 4
       WHEN 'MAY' THEN 5
       WHEN 'JUN' THEN 6
       WHEN 'JUL' THEN 7
       WHEN 'AUG' THEN 8
       WHEN 'SEP' THEN 9
       WHEN 'OCT' THEN 10
       WHEN 'NOV' THEN 11
       WHEN 'DEC' THEN 12
       ELSE NULL
       END AS month_number
FROM   your_table;
```

or the `DECODE` function:

```sql
SELECT DECODE(
         month_name,
         'JAN', 1,
         'FEB', 2,
         'MAR', 3,
         'APR', 4,
         'MAY', 5,
         'JUN', 6,
         'JUL', 7,
         'AUG', 8,
         'SEP', 9,
         'OCT', 10,
         'NOV', 11,
         'DEC', 12
       ) AS month_number
FROM   your_table;
```

or `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(month_name, 'MON', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'),
         'MM'
       ) AS month_number
FROM   your_table;
```

or `EXTRACT` and `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(
         MONTH FROM TO_DATE(month_name, 'MON', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')
       ) AS month_number
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: yes i am trying to avoid the case when, i am trying to find just a function it should be exist

Comment: This is the right answer. But the idea to save a Month as a separate column is horrible.

Comment: _"yes i am trying to avoid the case when, i am trying to find just a function "_  so put the demonstrated code inside a function.